# Several flume sinks in the same agent.conf file

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Is it possible to have several flume's agents (sinks) under the same configuration file (agent.conf)?

Answer (score 0):

I think so. It is a matter of include all the per-sinks configuration in the same agent.conf file. There is an example [here](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/ngsi_agent_conf/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way for FIWARE is using Dockers. So, let's imagine we need a Cygnus and we want the data to be "sinked" to MongoDB and MySQL.

A good practice would consist of making a Docker-compose file in order to build the application, but in this case, I'll show how to deploy all dockers needed separately.

We want to deploy a MySQL so Cygnus can store data in it. We can do it this way:

```
sudo docker run --name mysql_showcases \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbcygnus \
-e MYSQL_USER=cygnus \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=cygnus \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='%' \
-p 3306:3306 -it -v /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d -h mysql mysql/mysql-server:5.5
```

We want to deploy a MongoDB so Cygnus can also store data in it. We can do it this way:

```
sudo docker run --name mongo_showcases -v /data/mongodb:/data/db -d \
-h mongo mongo:3.6
```

Finally, we can deploy Cygnus using a Docker linked with both previous dockers:

```
docker run -d --name cygnus_showcases --link mysql_showcases --link mongo_showcases \
-p 8081:8081 -p 5050:5050 \
-e CYGNUS_MYSQL_HOST=mysql_showcases -e CYGNUS_MYSQL_PORT=3306 \
-e CYGNUS_MYSQL_USER=root -e CYGNUS_MYSQL_PASS=root \
-e CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo_showcases:27017 \
fiware/cygnus-ngsi
```

So, we've deployed a Docker, using Cygnus which will store data in a MongoDB and a MySQL database. We can also provide more "variables" to configure other sinks to where to store data in.